# How can I install php5-fpm and apache and configure the apache vhost?

Tags: apache2, php, cgi

I don't find a valid a description how can I install configure the apache vhost correctly. Can everybody help me?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName webpage.com
    ServerAlias www.webpage.com

    DocumentRoot /home/userdir/webpage.com

    Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin
    #Alias /php-fpm /home/userdir/webpage.com/php-fpm
    FastCgiExternalServer /home/userdir/webpage.com/php5-fcgi -flush -pass-header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION -host 127.0.0.1:11000
    #AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
    #Action appication/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php-fpm
    Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    ScriptAlias php5-fcgi /home/userdir/webpage.com/

    #DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        #DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/userdir/webpage.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        #DirectoryIndex index.php
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>


#   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And the output in the browser:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /php5-fcgi/index.php was not found on this server.
```

And the apache error log:

File does not exist: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.php

Comment: First make clear what you have tried. Then explain what the problem is - installing php5-fpm and apache, or configuring the vhost.

Comment: The problem I can't configure properly the vhost.

Comment: This is a lot better! If you start out like this, it saves us from trying to explain stuff that you already have working. That's a waste of our/my time, and for me a reason not to put more effort in it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.php` and put some text in it like "test", then save it. Try again. Furthermore I don't think that you should use a url path like /php5-fcgi. Just `http://localhost/index.php` (or .html) should do.

Comment: I use the webpage.com

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: In don't use the /php5-fcgi in the url.